# Unmirror Weight Paint

Tags: modifiers, rigging

I made this character with a mirror modifier (I just mirror the whole character), and now I have added an armature inside of it. But the weight paint is also mirrored. I want to make my character move in a none symmetrical way, but everything I do on one side, is always mirrored on the other.

Comment: I think you will need to apply the mirror modifier, this is standard procedure when creating an animated mesh. Make sure you like your character as-is though, as all edits in future will need to be done by hand.