# How to let mirrored half move independently

Tags: modeling, armature, mirror

I created a model using RPG Graphics tutorials, and was about to begin weight painting.  However, when I move one side of the armature, the other side mirrors its actions (model shown in tutorial does not do this).  I would like to be able to move the sides independently.  The right side of the mesh is mirrored from the left side.  In edit mode, vertices appear only on the original side.  Mesh on the original side bonds to armature, but that on the mirrored side does not; when I move the left arm, left arm mesh follows it, and right arm mesh mirrors it, but right armature does not follow.  I have tried selecting all, pressing 'p', and using the separate options.  Does not work.

Comment: could you please share the file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You find the following relevant: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31682/how-to-do-weight-paint-on-one-side-even-with-mirror-modifier/92112#92112

Answer (score 2):

You must apply mirror modifier before weighting.

[image]

The weight is a property of a vertex, the mirror modifier "copies" all vertex attributes, weight included, so - if you don't apply it - it will copy the weights from one side to the other.

Comment: It is not true that you need to apply the modifier. See that "Vertex Groups" option on the modifier settings? It mirrors weights to the appropriate mirrored group (e.g. all weights in arm.L will be mirrored to arm.R in the mirrored geo), provided the groups already exist.

Comment: @Sazerac you are right, but it's for basic understanding of Blender's data structure: using that option can be seen as a "magic button", I prefer to explain why the model moves both sides when mirror is not applied.

Answer (score 1):

I find that if I have the mirror modifier first and then the armature modifier, I can use automatic weights and manipulate the mesh independently with the armature.[image: mirror before armature]